# finding out iPhone usages information

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to buy a 2nd hand iPhone. is there any service exist where i can check when it was activated or when actually the user started using this iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

From [this webservice provided by Apple](https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do) you can get some data about the phone with its serial number.

It doesn't give you the purchase date but you can infer it from warranty end.